# Adding content to the left of Outlook 2013

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.0, outlook-addin, outlook-2013

In Outlook 2013 using VS2013, how do you create a tree structure using an add-in on the left hand side?  I know how to create TaskPanes and how do do all sorts with those, but what I can't seem to figure out is how to add stuff to the left side pane?

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is a tree structure you can create a folder in the default store and under this new folder you can create and manipulate your tree, always in the applications starts event, you can create your Outlook.MAPIFolder and in the Outlook.BeginShutdown event you delete the folder.

```
 //How to get de DefaultStore
 private Outlook.Store DefaultStore
    {
        get
        {
               return Outlook.Application.Session.DefaultStore;  
        }
    }
```

Or you can create your own Outlook.Store and save in a .pst file, a really good sample is from Add-in Express and shows how to create a new Outlook Personal Folders store https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/03/19/outlook-personal-folders-store/